# laravel, ubuntu and localhost data breach

Tags: mysql, laravel, security

I’m using Laravel 6.0 and a Ubuntu server to launch a website. The site has yet to launch and as I’m getting ready to – I’ve gotten an error when I’ve entered my password stating that my password has been compromised due to a data breach. I have a strong password and I’ve taken a lot of precautionary steps. I run clamav and get no viruses. I’ve tried to set generally strong passwords for passwords that matter. For the account where I get the message - they are test accounts where the password is basic and the same amongst most

[image]

I can probably call out that I’ve run composer update from the root account. I have set up another account on the server but I still call sudo as I haven’t seen another way to get that to execute properly for composer commands. This may have also happened after I ran updates on webpack as well locally.

I am also getting this error in my localhost (wamp) environment which I'd like to think adds a clue. I’ve never really had a problem with viruses on this machine that I work on. I run avast and malwarebytes and don’t get any viruses. I use git to upload to my server

I’m wondering what’s the best course forward.
Change all passwords
-mysql
-ubuntu
-laravel keys
I don’t necessarily want to reinstall everything on the server but if that’s what I have to do…

Comment: this has nothing to do with your website, Google have a psudo-db with a lot of user-password pairs that are been exposed in website breach, so you have to be awared about the security of your account/password, not your website

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome has a registry of "hacked" websites. Here is a article explaining how it works: [Better Password Protections in Chrome](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html)

When you open your website on the local address `127.0.0.1` Chrome thinks it is a real Website, and it compares it to their database of sites that have been compromised. So don't worry, it's just an error of Chrome not knowing that you are using a development server.